# Linking an ios app from Veeva iRep slide on an iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad

I want to link an app to a button from a Veeva iRep slide. I have the app url in a format something like this

`com.abc.xyz`

Using jquery, I am trying to link this app to the button.

```
$('#b1').on('click',function(){
   window.location = "irep://com.abc.xyz";   
});
```

As per the veeva documentation, I have also tried out

```
$('#b1').on('click',function(){
   window.location = "veeva://com.abc.xyz";   
});
```

Also I have tried out this, but I'm not exactly sure about this.

```
$('.app_test3').on('click',function(){
    window.location = "appname://com.abc.xyz";
});
```

Please note, this app is not installed on my iPad. So will this work? Need guidance on this one.

Answer (score 3):

The app needs to be installed and have its URL scheme registered, e.g. `appB` to provide links like `appB://some/deep/link`.

Then you can use this scheme in app A to link to app B, which will be opened (if it's installed). The link itself will be passed to app B so that it can take the appropriate actions.

Another thing you can do is link to the iTunes Store. This will open the App Store app showing the app you linked but will not directly open it, if it's installed.

Comment: Just to clarify, the string in the format `com.abc.xyz` or something like that is a url identifier right? So if the app is installed in my ipad, all I have to do is use this identifier and link it from the other app.

Comment: The URL scheme is `appB` in my example. What follows after that depends completely on how app B implements it. You can read more in the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html